Setting sampling probability when sparsifying a non-negative weighted graph
Given a set of $mn$ non-negative edges, with what probability should one keep every edge $w_{ij}$ if we want $\sim pmn$ non-zero weights in our sparsified and every edge is sampled with a probability that is proportional to their weight?
More concretely, how would one find a closed form expression for $K$ if we're sparsifying a graph $W$ using the rule
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
W^{sparse}_{ij} &= 
w_{ij} \; \; w.p. \;\; K \cdot w_{ij}\\
&= 0 \; \; else.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
If not a closed form expression necessarily, would there be an algorithm to do so? The idea is that given a probability of connection parameter $p$, how do we sample the weights of a graph $W$ using the above rule so that the new sparse graph has $pmn$ non-zero edges.
The cases I'm interested in in particular are when the weights $w_{ij}$ are distributed according to a folded normal distribution and the uniform distribution.

I don't understand the problem.  What do you mean by "want... non-zero weights"?  What does "in our sparsified" mean?  Some word seems missing.

Have you tried computing the expected number of non-zero weights in the sparsified graph, as a function of $K$?

Calculating the expected number of non-zerod as a function of K works -- I'd made a mistake before but redid it and it worked out

The expected number of non-zeros in the sparsified matrix will be $\sum_i^m \sum_j^n K |w_{ij}| = K||W||_{L1} = pmn$ which implies that $K = \frac{pmn}{||W||_{L1}}$.
